# CSS outline is appearing on unexpected places

Tags: css, outline

This may be a dumb question, but this thing is bothering me more than it should. It's a known fact that Google Chrome outlines `<input>` elements by default when they're focused. I don't like its default appearance so I implemented my own `outline` for the `focus` selector on my CSS:

```
#LoginForm input:focus {
    outline: #1F377A dotted 1px;
}
```

The original Chrome's implementation looks as follows (notice the blue outline *around* the text input):

[image: Chrome's outline on focus]

But by using my own css implementation it looks like this:

[image: My outline]

Why does my outline appears inside the text input and not around as chrome's default outline does?

These are the relevant css lines for my input element:

```
#LoginForm input {
    display: blocK;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
}

#LoginForm input:focus {
    outline: red solid 1px;
}

#LoginForm .textInput {
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
```

The only thing that let's me change between my own and chrome's outline is just commenting the `input:focus` selector and nothing more. I don't want to use borders, since the actually add to the size of the element and I don't want that.

Comment: i bet it's not the outline property but something else, probably the border with some colored shading...

Comment: Test `-webkit-appearance: none;` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the chrome dev tools, the outline is not a simple 1px outline but shows up as

```
:focus {
    outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-style: auto;
    outline-width: 5px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus, keygen:focus, select:focus {
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

The `outline-offset` is what you where looking for. To have a red outline simply add this to your style sheet:

```
:focus {
     outline-color: #f00;
}
```

If you also want it on other elements use:

```
.element:focus {
    outline-color: #f00;
    outline-style: auto;
    outline-width: 5px;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmvL3/) to play with.

---

*EDIT:*

To have the outline exactly on the border (and not inside of it) you have to set

```
outline-offset: 0;
```

to override the chrome user agent styles.

Comment: This works great! Thank you! by the way, since some browsers (e.g. midori or mobile browsers) don't use chrome's pretty outline (auto), that's why I was using a dotted outline (I used a solid one for the sake of visibility on the example) but I find strange that the shorthand property doesn't accept an offset value. I also have to note that when I use auto as style I don't need to specify an offset value: it's displayed at the border on chrome and other broswers (when others display it as `dotted`), but not when I use dotted or other styles. May this be a bug?

Comment: I didn't find anything on why the `outline-offset` is not part of the `outline` property. Concerning the second part of your comment. The `outline-offset`is still in effect even if you change the color and/or width. To have the `1px solid red` outline from the example above you have to explicitly set `outline-offset: 0;` to override the user agent stylesheet.